# Markov property of jump type diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the following jump-type SDE with two random Poisson measures $N_1$, $N_2$ and a Brownian motion $B_t$:

$dX_t= b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dB_t + \int{}F_1(X_t,u)N_1(dt,du) + \int{}F_2(X_t,u)N_2(dt,du)$

Assume the above SDE give a strong solution, which is a real-valued cadlag process $X$ for suitable condition on $F_i, b, \sigma$.

I'm looking for any references for proving that $X$ has the Markov property, in the best case with the use of strong solution property.

We already know that this is the case for Itō-Diffusions $dX_t=b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dB_t$ for example: https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/lecture-28-the-feynman-kac-formula/

It is possible to rewrite a Itō-Diffusion just depending on $B_t$ and start conditions $X_0$ w.r.t to a functional $F$.

Any idea if this method can be generalised to SDE as mentioned above?